# how to use wicked_pdf gem in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

I'm using wicked_pdf gem in a rails app and everything works fine. The problem is that I have installed wicked_pdf.exe because wicked_pdf gem doesn't work correctly.
It returns this error: Bad wkhtmltopdf's path for wicked_pdf ( Or similar).
This is my wicked_pdf  config:

```
    WickedPdf.config = {
  # Path to the wkhtmltopdf executable: This usually isn't needed if using
  # one of the wkhtmltopdf-binary family of gems.
  exe_path: 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe',
  #   or
  #exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')

  # Layout file to be used for all PDFs
  # (but can be overridden in `render :pdf` calls)
  # layout: 'pdf.html',
}
```

How can i use the gem in proper way? I need to send my app to another pc and I don't want to install the exe in every pc.
I don't want to use exe, i want to use only gem.

Answer (score 1):

```
exe_path: 'C://Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The github [documentation](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#installation) says:

> Because `wicked_pdf` is a wrapper for `wkhtmltopdf`, you'll need to
>   install that, too.
>
> The simplest way to install all of the binaries (Linux, OSX, Windows)
>   is through the gem wkhtmltopdf-binary. To install that, add a second
>   gem
>
> `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'`

So it seems that you will have to also include this binary in your app. Bundling the install should solve this. You may need to create some OS mapping inside your app to set `WickedPdf.config` (ex /usr/bin/local/wkhtmltopdf vs C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe)

Comment: Hi @whodini9! Thank you, but it still not working. I've installed gem 'wicked_pdf', gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary' with "exe_path: 'C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\wkhtmltopdf'" instead of "exe_path: 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'". This is runtime error: wkhtmltopdf is not executable

Comment: Can you try using the 2nd option: exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf'). Also in general its safer to use File.join("C:\","Program Files","#{foo}",bar)

Comment: still "wkhtmltopdf is not executable"